# How to consume this api?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am trying to consume this api http://simplewebapi1webapp1.azurewebsites.net/Help/Api/GET-api-HeadphonesJSON using python. I am new to consuming APIs, I learned consuming api, from this api http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json. As you can see this API has a dictionary as we go to that link. I am not able to see such dictionary in the first api. But I am getting a response <200> when I try to access that api. Please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think then endpoint you're looking for is here:
http://simplewebapi1webapp1.azurewebsites.net/api/HeadphonesJSON

You will consume it the same way (using something like requests) in python.